# Truncating to Word type

Tags: haskell

The following code truncates a number of type `Double` to one in the type `Word16` (although I suspect any other word type behaves similarly, I had to choose one for the example).

```
truncate1 :: Double -> Word16
truncate1 = fromIntegral . (truncate :: Double -> Int)
```

As you can read, I first truncate it to `Int` and only then I cast it to `Word16`. I benchmarked this function agains a direct truncation:

```
truncate2 :: Double -> Word16
truncate2 = truncate
```

Surprisingly to me, the first version (going thru the `Int` type first) performed much better. Or the second much worse. According to the criterion output:

```
benchmarking truncate/truncate1
mean: 25.42399 ns, lb -47.40484 ps, ub 67.87578 ns, ci 0.950
std dev: 145.5661 ns, lb 84.90195 ns, ub 244.2057 ns, ci 0.950
found 197 outliers among 100 samples (197.0%)
  97 (97.0%) low severe
  100 (100.0%) high severe
variance introduced by outliers: 99.000%
variance is severely inflated by outliers

benchmarking truncate/truncate2
mean: 781.0604 ns, lb 509.3264 ns, ub 1.086767 us, ci 0.950
std dev: 1.436660 us, lb 1.218997 us, ub 1.592479 us, ci 0.950
found 177 outliers among 100 samples (177.0%)
  77 (77.0%) low severe
  100 (100.0%) high severe
variance introduced by outliers: 98.995%
variance is severely inflated by outliers
```

To be honest, I just started using Criterion, so I'm not an expert using it, but I understand that `25.42399 ns` is a shorter execution time than `781.0604 ns`. I suspect that some specialization is playing a role here. Is it `truncate2` too slow? Being the case, can `truncate` be improved? Furthermore, anybody knows an even faster way? I feel like doing something wrong casting to a type I don't really use.

Thanks in advance.

I am compiling with GHC-7.4.2, optimizations enabled (`-O2`).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First, note that the module `GHC.Word` [includes the following](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.6.0.1/doc/html/src/GHC-Word.html) `RULE` pragma:

```
"truncate/Double->Word16"
    forall x. truncate (x :: Double) = (fromIntegral :: Int -> Word16) (truncate x)
```

This is a simple rewrite rule to perform precisely the optimization your `truncate1` provides. So we have a few questions to consider:

#### Why is this an optimization at all?

Because the default implementation of `truncate` is generic, to support any `Integral` instance. The speed difference you see is the cost of that generality; in the specific case of truncating one primitive type to another, there are much faster methods available.

So it seems that `truncate1` is benefiting from a specialized form, while `truncate2` is not.

#### Why is `truncate1` faster?

[In `GHC.Float`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.6.0.1/doc/html/src/GHC-Float.html), where the `RealFrac` instance for `Double` is defined, we have the following `RULE` pragma:

```
"truncate/Double->Int"              truncate = double2Int
```

Where `double2Int` is the optimized form we want. Compare this to the `RULE` mentioned earlier--apparently there's no similar primitive operation specifically for converting `Double` to `Word16`.

#### Why doesn't `truncate2` get rewritten as well?

[Quoth the GHC User's Guide:](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/rewrite-rules.html)

> GHC currently uses a very simple, syntactic, matching algorithm for matching a rule LHS with an expression. It seeks a substitution which makes the LHS and expression syntactically equal modulo alpha conversion. The pattern (rule), but not the expression, is eta-expanded if necessary.

Expressions being matched are not eta-expanded, which is to say that a rule matching on `forall x. foo x` will match in `bar y = foo y` but *not* in `bar = foo`.

Since your definitions are all written point-free, the `RULE` for `Double -> Int` matches, but the `RULE` for `Double -> Word16` does not.

Comment: This raises the question: Why isn't the truncate/Double-Word16 rule written as `truncate = (fromIntegral :: Int -> Word16) . (truncate :: Double -> Int)` so that it would apply in `truncate2`?

Comment: @GeoffReedy: That's a good question! But not one I can answer. I have a rough understanding of how rewrite rules *work*, but not how best to *use* them, unfortunately.

Comment: This makes sense and is approximately what I was thinking of! Thank you for your explanation. It's interesting that my optimization was exactly the rule written in `GHC.Word`!

Comment: @GeoffReedy Is it a valid excuse that those were about the first `RULES` I ever wrote and I wasn't even aware of the eta-reduction problem then? (I saw `RULES` using `forall x. ...`, and I followed the example.) I'm going to rewrite them so they fire pointfree and pointfull, but at the moment I can't validate because the `Typeable` change broke a couple of libraries.